# How to ensure highest-priority thread has first/best access to CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, scheduling, thread-priority

I have a system having CPU-expensive processing, but that is not time-critical. This same system is serving RESTful endpoints, which are time-critical, and tend to bog down badly when the other processing is running. I want to create two thread pools, one with high-priority threads and the other low-priority, such that the RESTful endpoint will always be snappy regardless of the other processing.

I created this experiment to try to understand Thread priorities:

```
object RunMeX extends App {

    val t1 = new Thread(SlowTask("A"))
    t1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
    val t2 = new Thread(SlowTask("B"))
    t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
    val t3 = new Thread(SlowTask("C"))
    val t4 = new Thread(SlowTask("D"))
    val t5 = new Thread(SlowTask("E"))

    t1.start
    t2.start
    t3.start
    t4.start
    t5.start
}

case class SlowTask(label:String) extends Runnable {
    def run = {
        val t = Timer()
        var m = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Long]()
        for( i <- 0 to 100; j <- 0 to 200) { 
            m += i*j
            val n = m.map(_+1)
        }
        println(label+" ::: "+t.time)
    }
}

case class Timer {
    val now = new java.util.Date().getTime
    def time = (new java.util.Date().getTime) - now
}
```

I have one more thread than I do CPU cores, to force some prioritization. The output I *expected* was the low-priority thread to clearly take the longest, the high-priority thread to clearly take the least time, and the remaining two to be somewhere in the middle. My actual results showed precious little difference in performance at all between the threads.

How can I ensure my highest-priority thread (i.e. the RESTful endpoint handling, represented by t2 here) always has first/best access to CPU?

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not a good idea to use the same JVM in latency-optimized workload (your REST API) as well as throughput-optimized workload (your CPU-intensive work). It will be difficult to tune the garbage collection in a way that's specific to the type of your workload. Simpler and smaller JVMs will be more predictable.

Specifically to your question, make sure you pass the `-XX:+UseThreadPriorities` flag as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm), and run the application as root if on Linux.